# clear textbox filled with datatime picker data on selection of check box

Tags: javascript, html

I have two text box and i filled them with the value using Datetime Picker.I also have a check box when it checked the two text box will be enable and the date time picker will be shown and when unchecked they will be clear and disable and the datetimer picker will be disappered. My code is as follows

```
<tr bgcolor="#DBE0F3" height="20">
 <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#DBE0F3">
  <span class="style1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="create_date" name="create_date" value="" onclick="javascript:return enableDisable(this.checked,'txtFromDate','txtToDate');" />
  Create Date : 
  </span>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#EEF3FA" >
 <td  align="right" bgcolor="#EEF3FA" class="td_left" style="color:#006666">
  From Date :
 </td>
 <td width="57%" colspan="2" class="td_right">
  <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" name="txtFromDate" value="" size="20px" onblur="if(this.value != ''){this.value =''}" disabled/>
  <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('txtFromDate','ddMMyy')">
   <img src="../../images/calendar_button.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Pick a date" border="0" />
  </a>    
 </td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FCFDFE" >
 <td  align="right" bgcolor="#EFEFF8" class="td_left" style="color:#006666">
  To Date :
 </td>
 <td width="57%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#EFEFF8" class="td_right">
  <input type="text" id="txtToDate" name="txtToDate" value="" size="20px" onblur="if(this.value != ''){this.value =''}" disabled/>
   <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('txtToDate','ddMMyy')">
    <img src="../../images/calendar_button.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Pick a date" border="0" />
  </a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
function enableDisable(bEnable,txtFromDate,txtToDate)
{
   if(bEnable==false){
            document.getElementById(txtFromDate).disabled=!(bEnable);
            document.getElementById(txtToDate).disabled=!(bEnable);
   }else
   {
            document.getElementById(txtFromDate).disabled=!(bEnable);
            document.getElementById(txtToDate).disabled=!(bEnable);
   }
}
```

I have no idea in jQuery.

I need a code where on clicking checkbox the fields will be enabled and take dates from the picker.When the fields disabled the date Time picker will not active/shown only will active when the check box is clicked and when the check box unchecked field will be clear and disabled and the datetime picker will be deactivate or hide.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Change Function to
function enableDisable(bEnable, txtFromDate, txtToDate) {
if (bEnable == true) {
    document.getElementById(txtFromDate).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    document.getElementById(txtToDate).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
} else {
    document.getElementById(txtFromDate).removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById(txtToDate).removeAttribute("disabled");

}

}
```

Comment: Its not working.At page startup the field was disabled but still i can pick date into that fields without selecting the check box.Another thing when I first click the check box the field value was in blur i.e. in disable formate when I uncheck the checkbox then it is enabled.So basically its not working.